# Schengen visa not stamped in the issuing country

Tags: transit, passport-stamps, schengen-visas

We traveled to Italy with a connecting flight in Athens with Aegean Airlines. We have a Schengen visa issued by the Italian embassy. The problem is once we arrived in Athens for the transit, they stamped our passports M and when we arrived in Italy we didn't get a stamp. When we left Italy we didn't get a stamp either, our passports were stamped in Greece when we departed. On our passports there is no proof of entering Italy.

Can this cause us problems when applying for a Schengen visa again?

Comment: For clarity, what travel itinerary did you state in your visa application?

Comment: If you’re concerned, for peace of mind you could always keep a copy of your flight reservation / boarding card.

Comment: My itinerary for the visa process was only italy rome florence venice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For travel in and out of the Schengen zone, your passport and visa are checked when entering and leaving the Schengen zone.

When travelling from Greece to Italy on arrival, you did not receive a stamp because you were already in the Schengen area. When travelling from Italy to Greece you received no stamp because you were not leaving the Schengen zone.

This is the normal procedure experienced by anybody visiting a country in the Schengen zone who arrives/leaves via a connecting flight in a different Schengen-zone country. It won't cause you any problems.

Answer (score -3):

This should not cause any problems, since this is normal procedure for connecting flights, and a great many of cheap-ish Schengen plane tickets will make you pass immigration before arriving at destination country.

I also have similar experience.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "cheap-ish" plane tickets, even passengers of the fanciest airlines will experience this if their entry into the Schengen zone is not their final destination.

Comment: @ChrisH you are right, but in my case there were direct flights available for more money. NB, I don't recommend anyone ever enter Schengen in Rome.

Comment: @alamar You may want to remove that bit from your answer, since it's misleading.